# Proof by induction, Inductive step simplicifation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction

[image]

I've already checked the Base Case, I'm having trouble with the inductive step.

By inductive hypothesis $n = k >= 2$, that is $2^{k} < (k+1)!$

Inductive Step: Prove statement is true for $n = k+1$, that is $2^{k+1} < (k+2)$

$2^{k+1} = 2^{k} *2 <2*(k+1)!$

How do I turn the $(k+1)!$ to $(k+2)!$

Comment: Well $(k+2)!=(k+2)(k+1)! $.  How does that compare to $2*(k+1)!.  Actually you could say (I've never seen anyone say it) that $(k+2)!=(k+2)(k+1)!=2*(k+1)! + k (k+1)!>2*(k+1)! + 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't that trivial?
since $k \geq 2$, $k+2 > 2$, therefore, $2^{k+1}=2^k*2 < 2*(k+1)! < (k+2)*(k+1)! = (k+2)!$